# Can't use expressions in clauses for racket pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

In racket I made this basic piece of code. However racket doesn't seem to like the first clause - trying to run this, I get the error *"match: syntax error in pattern in: (- 3 9)"*

```
(define/match (prob i)
    [((- 3 9)) 0]
    [(_) 4]
)
```

The weird thing is that if instead of the subtraction procedure, I used the "list" procedure (i.e. ((list 3 9)) instead of ((- 3 9)) ), the code works. What gives?

Comment: If you want to evaluate the expression and compare the value for equality, try `(== (- 3 9))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to check whether the argument `i` is equal to the value that (- 3 9) resolves to, then the issue is that Racket `match` forms do not accept arbitrary expressions as patterns. For more information on what kind of patterns can be used with `match` forms, check out the Racket documentation on [Pattern Matching](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) (you may notice that `(list ...)` is included among the allowed patterns, as you observed!). However the simple answer (as Alex Knauth commented) is to replace `(- 3 9)` with `(== (- 3 9))`.

On the other hand, if your goal is to check whether the argument supplied to `(prob i)` is literally the expression (- 3 9), regardless of what that might evaluate to, then `define/match` will not suffice. Racket functions are [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). So when someone passes an expression as the argument `i` to your `prob` function, `i` is equal to the *evaluated result* of that expression, viz

```
(define (some-function some-argument)
    some-argument) ; we just get the number 3 for some-argument
                   ; and have no way of knowing via this function
                   ; that someone actually passed us the expression
                   ; (- (- 9 1) 5)

(some-function (- (- 9 1) 5))
```

We would have to use a different tool, called a [macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html). Macros operate on the text  of the program before symbols are evaluated. A macro implementation of your `(prob i)` function would work like this on the REPL:

```
> (define-syntax-rule (prob i)
    (if (equal? 'i '(- 3 9))
      0
      4))
> (prob (- 3 9))
0
> (prob -6)
4
> (prob 78)
4
```

That is called a "syntax rule". It quotes out the argument `i`, then compares it to the quoted expression `(- 3 9)` to see if that was supplied as `i`. Let me know if you're still having any issues! Good luck!